# Change text color from canvas with Select option

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a canvas and I can introduce text into it. I'm trying to change the color of that text from canvas using Select object but I failed. Can someone help me with this one? This is the code and thank you for your time.

Here is **JS** for text introduction into the canvas:

```
$(function(){

   var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
   var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

   ctx.font= "bold 90px Arial";
   ctx.textAlign="center";

   var $text1=document.getElementById("sourceText1");

   $text1.onkeyup=function(e){ redrawTexts(); }

   function redrawTexts(){
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
       wrapText(ctx,$text1.value,66.5, 82,"Arial");

   }

   function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace){
      var words = text.split(' ');
      var line = '';
      var lineHeight=fontSize;

      context.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;

      for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
          var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
          var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
          var testWidth = metrics.width;
          if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
             context.fillText(line, x, y);
             line = words[n] + ' ';
             y += lineHeight;
          }
          else {
             line = testLine;
          }
      }
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      return(y);
   }

 }); // end $(function(){});
```

And here is **JS** for changing the color:

```
  var main8 = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var render8 = main8.getContext("2d");

  function color(v8) {
    switch(v8) {
     // top: 103px; left: 210px
        case "green":
            main8.fillStyle = 'green';
            break;

        case "red":
            main8.fillStyle = "#ff3300";
            break;
            }
  }
```

Here is **HTML:**

```
 <input id="sourceText1" type="text" style="height: 32px;width: 223px;">

 <select name="colours" onchange="color(this.value)">
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
```

Here is the **CSS:**

```
  #canvas{border:2px dotted transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `fillStyle` on `main8`, which is the canvas element.
The property should be set on the canvas context, i.e. `main8.getContext("2d")`.

Moreover you should also redraw the text via your `redrawTexts` function.

```
function color(v8) {
  switch(v8) {
   // top: 103px; left: 210px
      case "green":
          main8.getContext("2d").fillStyle = 'green';
          break;

      case "red":
          main8.getContext("2d").fillStyle = "#ff3300";
          break;
  }
  redrawTexts();
}
```

Try it out:

```js
  var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.font= "bold 90px Arial";
  ctx.textAlign="center";

  var $text1=document.getElementById("sourceText1");

  $text1.onkeyup=function(e){ redrawTexts(); }

  function redrawTexts(){
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      wrapText(ctx,$text1.value,66.5, 82,"Arial");

  }

  function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace){
     var words = text.split(' ');
     var line = '';
     var lineHeight=fontSize;

     context.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;

     for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
         var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
         var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
         var testWidth = metrics.width;
         if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
            context.fillText(line, x, y);
            line = words[n] + ' ';
            y += lineHeight;
         }
         else {
            line = testLine;
         }
     }
     context.fillText(line, x, y);
     return(y);
  }

  var main8 = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var render8 = main8.getContext("2d");

  function color(v8) {
    switch(v8) {
     // top: 103px; left: 210px
        case "green":
            main8.getContext("2d").fillStyle = 'green';
            break;

        case "red":
            main8.getContext("2d").fillStyle = "#ff3300";
            break;
    }
    redrawTexts();
  }
```

```css
#canvas{border:2px dotted transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<input id="sourceText1" type="text" style="height: 32px;width: 223px;">

 <select name="colours" onchange="color(this.value)">
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
 
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: For detailed info see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle)

Comment: I tried with this but still doesn't change the text color. When I select green the text should change to green, but it's still black.

Comment: @P.Pann I have added a snippet. Run it and try to write something in the input, then change the color to either green or red

Comment: Hahaha I tried the same thing and didn't work for me. Thank you very much for your help, now it works. You're the best!